# How to create widget system in php(xenForo, Zend framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, widget, system, xenforo

I would like to ask which is the best way to build a widget system with PHP for own cms Addon(xenforo zend framework).

For now I plan following steps:

- At first I would like to have a directory "widgets" where I can put all widgets.
- Each widget will habe a file "widgetIndex.php" where the HTML code of the widget will be generated (for Example function "generateHTML").

  `class myWidgetName{
            function generateHTML(){
      return the html of the widget;
         }
       }`
- When I build the View, the System will include the widget file

  `include(myWidgetName/widgetIndex.php);`

and get the html from the function. And this for all widgets.

```
foreach(widgets_found as widget)
 {
    include widget."/".widgetIndex.php;
    $myWidgetHtmlArray .= generateHTML();
 }
```

Is this a good Idea or there is a better solution to realize that?

Best regards
Tony

Comment: Is there any solution?